# Image Resizing without white border

Tags: adobe-photoshop-elements

I have photoshop elements and I need to resize an image to a specific size for uploading to our website. what I would usually do is open image then resize, change the width, ok, then go to image, canvass, change to pixels then input the height and ok then save it and it's fine. This time however I am getting a white border around the image once I've resized, how do I get rid of this please?

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a new document with the exact size needed for you website, then drag the image on it.
The thing is that if your image doesn't have the same aspect ratio, you will end with borders *(just like when you try to see a 16:9 movie on a 4:3 display)*.
You can transform *(CTRL+T)* the image and fit it *(holding shift to not mess around the proportions)* but you will end with a little crop.
When i see myself in those situations and don't want to crop, i paint those edges with same colors and content.

Answer (score -1):

Or you could just use the crop tool to remove the white borders.

Comment: The Asker emphasised they need a specific size.

Comment: Yes... if they drag the correctly-sized image and it has white borders, they can crop them off. Then the remaining image will be the correct size.

Comment: *scratches back of head* If take a correctly-sized image, and you crop something off, how can it still be the correct size? I think we're having a misunderstanding here :)

Comment: I think we do too. Let's call this one good, okay? ;)